# Automate Moving Items into Folders in a List

Tags: designer-workflow, custom-list, archive, large-lists

When I have large lists or new ones that could become large lists I would like to create an automated way to move items into folders to help with performance on the root level of the list.

For a custom list that has folders enabled I am aware that as an administrator I can use the content and structure part of SharePoint to move items into folders manually. I think it would be great to automate this in some way using workflows.

I was planning on moving items into folders by Year / Month biased on the created date of the items. Other things I could add to my lists would be a status to indicate when the archive move would be appropriate for the items to move into the folders such as a "completed" status of some sort.

My archive folder tree would be as follows

- Archive 2016

  - January-16
  - February-16
  - March-16

etc...

Looking forward to your ideas around automatic folder archiving, This would be done on a SharePoint 2013 on prem site where 2010/2013 workflows could be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot move items with a workflow. You could create an item with all the field values inside a folder. Or you can copy the item into another list.

Comment: Thought so, but it was good to ask. :-) I think we have a third party tool that might have some new options in workflow to do the task that I can try. Also I think there are some ways of doing it with PowerShell / task scheduler if need be.

Comment: I'm almost positive you can do it with powershell.